# How to create time AM/PM range slider in ng5-slider

Tags: angular9

I am using [ng5-slider](https://github.com/angular-slider/ng5-slider) in angular 9 project. I have no idea how to create a time range slider using is package.

**Screentshot::** https://nimb.ws/qBRT9S

Please tell me how to made this.

Comment: this can help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2yuvz?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

First you should upgrade to their new package for Angular 6+. It's so easy all you need to do is follow these few instructions.
[UOGRADUNG.md](https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider/blob/HEAD/UPGRADING.md)
Don't worry you won't feel the change because everything is almost the same.

This is a time slider I made and I believe it's what you are asking for.

```
  timeOptions: Options = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 23 + 59 / 60,
    step: 1 / 60,
    noSwitching: true,
    translate: (value: number, label: LabelType): string => {
      const h = Math.floor(value);
      const hh = h === 0 ? 12 : h < 10 ? `0${h}` : h < 13 ? h : h - 12;
      const mm = formatNumber((value - h) * 60, this.locale, '2.0-0');
      const aa = value < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
      return `${hh}:${mm} ${aa}`;
    },
    animate: false,
  };
```

When you get the value if you need to send it in the same format you can convert it the same way.

Note that I'm using Angular DecimalPipe to make sure the minutes are 2 digits, and I could use it for hours too but I found no need for it there.

```
import { DecimalPipe, formatNumber } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}
```

I hope this is useful.. :D